# Copying Cells from Workbook to Workbook Results in "Subscript Out of Range"

Tags: vba, excel, copy, range

Good day.

I am trying to write a code that will essentially select cells (left to right) from "A - M" and (downwards) up until the last used row.
Then, once selected, I was to copy them to another workbook.

This is the code that I tried to use:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:M" & LastRow).Copy _
    Workbooks("Converter.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```

Everything else in the code works except for this line.
And the result is this:

```
Run-time error '9':

Subscript out of range
```

Thanks.

PS.  The "LastRow" Variable I used, I just pulled that out of a tutorial.  That's not a personal user-defined variable, so I am not sure if that's actually from VBA's Documentation.

Comment: try take away `.CurrentRegion` for the destination cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned you do not have a calculation for LastRow.

1. Always put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module. It forces you to declare your variables and will help you recognize if something you got from another coder is "built-in" or not.
2. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920) about determining the last row in a range.
3. From that post, you should have a calculation such as the following before your line of code ...

   ```
   LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   ```

Comment: Ah... I see.  So, 'Option Explicit' will be an automatic aid.  Thank you.  But I have to ask, though.  What is 'xlUp' ?

Comment: xlUp is a constant, built in functionality of VBA for Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Please close all the workbooks and reopen and then try with below code

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:M" & lastrow).Copy Workbooks("Converter.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
End Sub
```